Dynamic value with TOP in SQL Server in Java native query
I need to render dynamic value with TOP in SQL Server native query in Java.
This is my query:
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT TOP :count caller_id from Call_details where date = :todayDate group by caller_id ORDER by COUNT(*) DESC")
findTopCallerByDate(@Param("count") int count, @Param("todayDate") Date todayDate);

I am getting this error:

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [SELECT TOP ? caller_id  from call_disposition where date = ? group by caller_id ORDER by COUNT(*) DESC] [Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]

I am using Java 17 with Spring Boot and SQL Server as the database.

So what are you stuck on? What is your question?

This doesn't look like plain Java but more like you're using Spring. If so you should definitely mention this. And I'm also not sure TOP :count would work as :count would be expected to be a value passed to the query but in your case it would be an intrinsic part of the query itself. You might have to either use the maximum value here and then truncate the result to count elements or build the query dynamically inside your method.

Top (:count) perhaps

So you still don't ask a question?

If you want to use anything other than a literal for TOP (such as a parameter, expression or subquery) it must be in parentheses. I believe not putting even literals in parenthesis is deprecated as well.

As suggested by @Siggemannen, paranthesis worked for me.
Like this:
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT TOP (:count) caller_id from Call_details where date = :todayDate group by caller_id ORDER by COUNT(*) DESC")
findTopCallerByDate(@Param("count") int count, @Param("todayDate") Date todayDate);

